# Multithreading application get its optimum using 16 thread although the computer has 32 cores

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have AMD Opteron(tm) 6282SE 2.6 GHZ  32 cores (2 processors 16 core each)
I have C# mathematical application which i can run on parallel cores.

The optimum performance that i get for the main part of my app is when i use 16 threads (i.e. divide the work to 16 threads)the optimal running time for this part is 1MS.

If I use more than 16 threads i get more than 1MS.

My question is why i can't i parallel this part to more threads assuming that i have 32 cores.

This is the code that run in parallel.

```
int N = 238;
int P = 16;

int Chunk = N / P;
AutoResetEvent signal = new AutoResetEvent(false);
// use a counter to reduce
int counter = P;

// kernel transitions   
for (int c = 0; c < P; c++)
{           
    // for each chunk
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate(Object o)
    {
        int lc = (int)o;
        for (int i = lc * Chunk; i < (lc + 1 == P ? N : (lc + 1) * Chunk); i++)
        {
           // do something
        }
        if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref counter) == 0)
        {
            signal.Set();
        }
    }, c);
}
signal.WaitOne();
```

Comment: Amdahl's law is fundamental: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahmdal%27s_Law

Comment: I would try to implement same thing with `System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For` and compare the results

Comment: Good question, and I don't have the answer, but can you use Monitor instead of AutoResetEvent? AutoResetEvent is a kernal mode sync object which is considerably slower than a managed sync object like monitor. I totally guessing here, but maybe using AutoResetEvent introduces some thing that using Monitor would avoid?

Comment: @HansPassant: That is interesting but it doesn't say anythign about why it would become slower if run on more cores, it just says what the maximum speed increase might be.

Comment: This depends a good deal on the mysterious `// do something` block. Specifically, you should look at how your program accesses the memory from the perspective of caching.

Comment: *Concurrency Hazards: False Sharing* http://www.nickbutler.net/Article/FalseSharing

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - that's what I was thinking.  If the chunk boundaries do not coincide with cache lines, there may be a lot of false sharing.

Comment: That, and N is very small.  We don't know what it is indexing but,  unless it is an array of large, complex objects with lengthy methods, it may be too small for effective concurrency.

Comment: @dasblinkenligh N is indeed small but in other parts of my apps (less heavy parts) i managed to parallel using 8 threads and get result of 0.1MS so i think that there is room to parallel more

Comment: Hi. I wrote that article on false sharing. Feel free to contact me via my website if you're still having problems.

Answer (score 3):

First off, I think you should definitely replace your construct with the new .NET 4.0 `Parallel.For` construct:

```
Parallel.For(0, N,
    i => 
    {
       // do something
    });
```

Secondly, you are in fact using two CPUs with 16 cores each. Most likely the scheduler is smart enough to exploit locality and schedule all your 16 threads on the same CPU. When the other CPU comes into play, depending on your computation, accessing shared data needs to be passed all the way through main memory to ensure coherence between the two CPUs. This could be very costly.

Comment: @Tudor: why not write the entire answer before posting then? I've no problem with giving a brief answer and then expanding on it but it does feel a little bit like posting "first!" when you post something that isn't an answer and then edit an answer into it...

Comment: Actually, using `Parallel.For` might solve his problem, so it's definitely worth testing this change alone IMO.

Comment: I tried all of the above suggestions but it didn't help. I tried to use Parallel.For(0, N,
    i => 
    {
       // do something
    });
it gave me the same result of ~1MS i tried to use Monitor instead of AutoResetEvent and i tried to set the min threads in the thread pool. It is very strange that the optimum is in 16 threads exactly, considering that i have 2 processors of 16 each.

Comment: @user1211587: Can you please post what you are doing in `// do something`? As I've mentioned in my answer, it's possible that data exchanges between the two processors are the cause of the slow-down.

Comment: @user1211587 the "do something" block is a simple mathematical application. it contains many mathematical calculation (simple operation like log, ^ etc) It also contain simple c# code (many if, while sorting etc)

Comment: Any shared data structures or values?

Comment: There is 2 arrays that are shared among the threads. Each thread has its own part so no synchronization is needed. i tried spacing and padding described in http://www.nickbutler.net/Article/FalseSharing but it didn't help

Answer (score 3):

`ThreadPool` is reactive and it can take a while until new threads are added to the pool. Basically if there are not enough threads for sometime, it increases the thread pool size and when there are more idles again, it brings it back. So it fluctuates between **min** and **max** size set by [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) object - accessible to get back or set.

If you know how many threads you need, use [SetMinThreads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads.aspx) to **ensure** you have enough threads at the start.

Comment: I have tried to set the min threads of the threadpool it didn't help. The default min size was 32. i tried to increase it but as mentioned it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was because my EXE file was compiled to 32 bit and the operating system was 64 bit.

From [64-bit Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/64-bit-apps):

> Due to the design of x86 emulation and the WOW64 subsystem for the
>   Itanium processor family, applications are restricted to execution on
>   one processor.